# Share Azure Compute Gallery between Subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

We have been using ARM templates to deploy multiple VMs to a single Azure subscription for some time. Recently we created multiple additional subscription and want to access the Azure Compute Gallery across all of the subscription and use the ARM template to deploy VMs. However, when we try to deploy VMs in the new subscriptions (all are in the same tenant and part of the same AAD) we get the following error

"Id /subscriptions/{subId}/resourceGroups/{asgRG}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/{acgName}/images/SWDC5/latest is not a valid resource reference."

RBAC sharing is enabled and below is the code snippet.

```
"storageProfile": {
     "osDisk": {
        "name": "[concat(variables('vmNamePrefix'), copyIndex('virtualMachineLoop', 1), '-osdisk')]",
        "createOption": "FromImage",
        "managedDisk": {
            "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
        },
        "deleteOption": "[parameters('osDiskDeleteOption')]"
      },
      "imageReference": {
          "id": "[concat('/subscriptions/', variables('subscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', variables('acgRG'), '/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/', variables('galleryImageName'), '/images/', variables('operatingSystemValues')[parameters('image')].galleryImageDefinitionName, '/', parameters('imageVersion'))]"
       }
},
```

Help with this issue will be much appreciated as I cannot see what I am doing wrong with the imageReference.

I have hard coding the image version, providing the reference via a variable, but the result is the same.